# Use properties of divisibility to prove that if $a$ divides $b$, $b$ divides $c$ then $a$ divides $7b+5c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Started it with this proof,

Let $b=k_1a$ and $c=k_2b$. Then,

$7b + 5c = 7(k_1a) + 5(k_2b)$, let k be equal to $k_1$ and $k_2$.

$7b + 5c = 7(ka) + 5 (kb)$

$7b + 5c = k(7a + 5b)$..........

$1)$ What properties to use?
$2)$ I'm not sure with my solution.

Comment: Do NOT let $k=k_1=k_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=x_1a$ and $c=x_2b$. Thus, $$c=x_1x_2a$$

So $$7b+5c=a(7x_1+5x_1x_2)$$ So $a|7b+5c$

Answer (score 1):

About your working, we can't just claim $k=k_1=k_2$.

In fact, there is nothing special about the numbers $7$ and $5$.

Consider $\beta b + \gamma c$, let $b=k_1a$ and $c=k_2b$

Then we have $\beta b+\gamma c=\beta k_1a + \gamma k_2 b$.

Now recall that your goal is to get a a factor of $a$, hence it makes sense to express the $b$ as a multiple of $a$, then you can factorize them out.

$$\beta b+\gamma c=\beta k_1a + \gamma k_2 b=\beta k_1 a +\gamma k_2(k_1a) = a(\beta k_1 + \gamma k_2k_1)$$